# Save multiple times in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to save 10 times in Cakephp using Save function with for loop but it doesn't seem to work. It only saves one data.

How can we make it so it saves multiple data at one call?

Below is my code...

```
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $unique_id = $this->_unique($userData['User']['id']); // Unique id with userid as initial prefix
        $this->data['Invite'] = array('invited_user' => $userData['User']['id'], 'unique_id' => $unique_id);
        $this->User->Invite->save($this->data['Invite']);
            }
```

Comment: you can loop 10 times to get the unique ids, put them all in array, and do a saveAll

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call Model::create( ) for each iteration of the loop. IE:

```
<?php
    for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ){
        $this->User->Invite->create( );
        $unique_id = $this->_unique($userData['User']['id']);
        $this->data['Invite'] = array('invited_user' => $userData['User']['id'], 'unique_id' => $unique_id);
        $this->User->Invite->save($this->data['Invite']);
        unset( $this->data[ 'Invite' ] );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the following book, page 94: Source: Bari, Ahsanul. CakePHP Application Development (p. 94). Packt Publishing. Kindle Edition. This is the what you can find in the book, and the answer to this question:

```
$this->Book->create();
$this->Book->save($this->data);
```

> Note: It is important to call the model's create() method just ahead
>   of calling the model's save() method if the intention is to create a
>   new record.

In other words, you need to use create() before save() every time you use save().