# Uploading multiple pictures from the same form in CakePHP 1.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a one-to-many relationship where one House can have many Pictures. The models that I have are "House" and "Picture". I am using CakePHP 1.2 and I can upload one picture successfully by using this:

```
echo $form->input('Picture.filename', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => __l('Image')));
```

In my houses_controller.php file, I have this code to save the picture and corresponding association with its house:

```
$this->House->Picture->save($this->data['Picture']);
```

But I need to save several pictures now. I read the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html and based on that information, I am trying to use this:

```
echo $form->input('Picture.0.filename', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => __l('Image 1'));
echo $form->input('Picture.1.filename', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => __l('Image 2'));
```

Then my houses_controller.php file has this:

```
$this->House->Picture->saveAll($this->data['Picture']);
```

I see that one new record is saved in my pictures table, but I was expecting to see two new entries in my table because I should have added two pictures, not only one. Any ideas about why this may not be saving two pictures for me? Thank you.

Comment: Your question says Cake 1.2, but the tag is 1.3.  Which one?

Comment: I used the tag "cakephp-1.3" because I could not find a tag "cakephp-1.2" and CakePHP 1.2 and 1.3 are at least close enough to assume that they still behave similarly. CakePHP 2.x and 3.x is likely to have more differences. I do not think I have enough privileges to create tags yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$this->Deal->Picture->save($this->data['Picture'][0]);
$this->Deal->Picture->save($this->data['Picture'][1]);
```

Using `$this->data['Picture']` was not sufficient because the array was returning multiple elements, so I had to reference each with the corresponding index such as `$this->data['Picture'][0]` for the first element, `$this->data['Picture'][1]` for the second one, etc.

NOTE: It was not saving two records for me, even thought I was using save() twice. But that was another issue. You can read the answers at [Save multiple times in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836507/save-multiple-times-in-cakephp/44984499#44984499) for the corresponding solution. Basically you need to use create() before you use save().